# Classification tree tool and integration with a web site

Tags: json, web, classification, weka

A general question. I have used i.e. Weka classifier model functionallity in their tool. But is there a way to "call Weka" and get a model in response from a website?
It is not important that it is Weka, but I want to implement some simple classification based on a json coming from a web-site.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) webservice in Java which loads your model and makes predictions using data it receives, sending back the predictions in a suitable format. There are a number of frameworks for writing such webservices (e.g., [JAX-RS](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jax-rs.html)).

In terms of using the Weka API, check out the [Use Weka in your Java code](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/) article.